# Type error: invalid 'in' operand e in jquery 1.10.2v

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have upgraded to jQuery 1.10.2 in my application, and I am getting an error in my code (in `$.each`).

> 'invalid 'in' operand e' .

This error occured after upgrading jQuery. In '`this._currentFilterbarValue`', there is a string value which I need to check against some condition.

```
_CheckForSkipInput: function () {
    var IsSkip = false;
    if (this._currentFilterColumn.type == "String") {
        var stringSkipInput = new Array(">", "<", "=", "!");
        $.each(this._currentFilterbarValue, function (index, value) {
            if (jQuery.inArray(value, stringSkipInput) != -1)
                IsSkip = true;
        });
    }
    return IsSkip;
},
```

Comment: what type of `_currentFilterbarValue` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying is to iterate through the characters in `this._currentFilterbarValue`(which is a string) and therefore `jQuery.each()` is failing

> The **`$.each()`** function can be used to iterate over any collection,
>   *whether it is an object or an array.*

So try like

```
 var IsSkip = false;
 if (this._currentFilterColumn.type == "String") {
     var stringSkipInput = new Array(">", "<", "=", "!");
     for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
         if (jQuery.inArray(s[i], stringSkipInput) != -1) IsSkip = true;
     }
 }
 return IsSkip;
 },
```

Another approach,

Converting your string `this._currentFilterColumn` to **`character array`** and then iterating using `$.each()`

```
var arr = this._currentFilterColumn.split("");  //Converting a string to char array
$.each(arr, function (index, value) {  //Now iterate the character array
  if (jQuery.inArray(value, stringSkipInput) != -1) IsSkip = true;
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Praveen. I will try this way. Hope it will work. Will accept your answer once i checked.